Entire function mapping horizontal lines to horizontal lines must be linear with real derivative
It's immediate that $f(x+iy) = u(x) + iv(x,y)$. So, $f'(s+it) = u_x(s)$.
But why should this be a real constant? What am I missing?

Do you know that a holomorphic function which takes only real values is necessarily constant?

Yes. Got it. Thanks a lot.

Only the Cauchy-Riemann differential equations are needed for this conclusion. If $f = u+iv$ maps horizontal lines to horizontal lines then
$$
 f' = u_x + i v_x 
$$
is real-valued, so that $v_x$ is identically zero. Then
$$
 f'' = u_{xx} + i v_{xx} = (v_x)_y +i (v_x)_x
$$
is identically zero, so that $f'$ is constant, i.e. $f$ is linear function.

As Martin pointed out, $f'(z)$ is a holomorphic function taking only real values. By Little Picard Theorem, it must be constant.
